Где ставится запятая?

Этой зимой было мало снега и трещали жесткие морозы.

Почему не ставится запятая перед союзом "и"? Тут же две грамматические основы: "было" и "трещали морозы".

Потому что "этой зимой" - общее обстоятельство. При однократном И запятая не ставится.
